# LINQ vb.net Not IsDBNull

Tags: vb.net, linq, dbnull

I have the following query that is supposed to filter out null values in the given groupfield but unfortunately returns an empty object when the source dataset contains null values in that field:

```
Dim SelectQuery = From q1 In loadedData.data.AsEnumerable
                  Order By q1(aGroupField)
                  Where Not IsDBNull(q1(aGroupField)) 
                        AndAlso q1(aGroupField) <> ""
                  Select New With {.groupField = q1(aGroupField)}
```

Comment: You could use the strongly typed `Field` extension and `String.IsNullOrEmpty`: `From q1 in loadedData.data Where Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(q1.Field(Of String)(aGroupField))`. But i must admit that I'm not sure if it solves your issue.

Comment: Btw, what is an empty object?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but I'm afraid that didn't work (although it works fine if the value isn't null). SelectQuery is "nothing"

Comment: To be more specific its table property is "Nothing"

Comment: Strange because `Field` supports nullables and automatically converts a `DBNull.Value` to the nullable type(or `Nothing` for reference types).

Comment: This doesn't work either: Select New With {.groupField = If(String.IsNullOrEmpty(q1.Field(Of String)(aGroupField)), "", q1.Field(Of String)(aGroupField))}